# Scala-Redis: How to connect a global redis cache in Scala?

Tags: scala, redis

I am using [scala-redis](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis) to make a connection to global redis database. I am able to connect easily with the locally running redis server but not sure what to pass in the constructor to connect with the global database. Tried passing username, password and port number but didn't work out.

I am using memcached protocol.

What do I mean by global redis-cache?

I have configured a cache on https://app.redislabs.com/
[image]

I am using these credentials:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share some details?
What is meant by Global Redis Cache? Is that you are trying to access it in AWS?

If in AWS then you have to create a script (Cloud Formation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ElastiCache.html) that creates the connection with AWS Redis Cache. Then provide the following config in application-prod.conf.

//NOTE: ELASTICACHE_ENDPOINT is your AWS REDIS endpoint

```
play.cache.redis {
  bind-default: false
  default-cache: "redis"
  source: standalone
  dispatcher: contexts.blockingCacheDispatcher

      instances {
        cache-name-1 {
          connection-string: ${?ELASTICACHE_ENDPOINT}
          source: connection-string
          database: 1
        },
        cache-name-2 {
          connection-string: ${?ELASTICACHE_ENDPOINT}
          source: connection-string
          database: 1
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Manohar, sorry for the confusion... and I haven't setup the redis cache on AWS. Although technically it's set on AWS only but not from my end rather redis cloud has done that for me...  I have added screenshots for the same. Also can I am not using `play.cache.redis` can you point some more documentation around that?